# How to parse data from firebase and then save it within a model. Swift3 MVC format

Tags: swift, firebase, model-view-controller, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user class within my firebaseDB. Its what you would expect a flat file DB would look like: users->UID->profile->key/values. I am trying to implement best practice within my code so I want the data to be handled by the User model in my Xcode project. How would I go about parsing the data and saving it as class variables within my model.

```html
class User {
    private var _username: String
    private var _uid: String
    
    var uid: String {
        return _uid
    }
    
    
    var username: String {
        return _username
    }
    
    
    init (uid: String, username:String) {
                self._uid = uid
                self._username = username
    }
    
    func getUserData() {
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let users = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
                for (key, value) in users { // We use the for in loop to iterate through each key/value pair in the database which is stored as a dictionary.
                    if let dict = value as? Dictionary<String, Any> { // This gets us inside the user ID
                        if let profile = dict["profile"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> { // This gets us inside the profile
                            if let username = profile["username"] as? String {
                                self._uid = key // Stores the UID of the user as the key.
                                self._username = username
                            } else {
                                let username = profile["name"] as? String
                                self._uid = key
                                self._username = username!
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

This is what I am trying to do but I am lost as to how I would actually store the data values within the class. FYI: username is an attribute under profile.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is conceptually wrong. You have a class that represents a single User, not multiple Users. Looking at your code, you're trying to store multiple users into a single user class. What is your final intention? to create an array of users? if so, perhaps you should consider creating a Users class, in which there would be an array of "User" typed items. In this way you could push each user to the array. If this isn't what you want - please clarify your question.

Comment: I am just looking to store for a singular user, however I will create another for multiple users at a later point. For now I just want to know how I can store one

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to build a user profile page. This would entail displaying their information

Answer (score 0):

You are currently looping through the entire list of users in the database and assigning the User properties repeatedly, overwriting the value from the previous loop cycle.

In order to get the correct user values assigned, you will need a way of knowing the correct path to the values. I would suggest saving the users using their assigned Firebase UID.

If you know the correct UID to look up you can then implement the following code:

```
func getUserData() {

    DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(_uid).child("profile").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let profileDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            print("Error fetching user")
            return
        }

        self._username = profileDict["username"] as? String ?? profileDict["name"] as! String

    })
}
```

The way that "username" is force unwrapped in your original code doesn't appear safe but I'm assuming you are certain that it will work out. Otherwise the following line should be changed to safely unwrap the optional:

```
self._username = profileDict["username"] as? String ?? profileDict["name"] as! String
```

Comment: So I implemented this and it didn't work to set the data, however I realize the for loop was unnessacary

Comment: Could you share the implementation, the data is most likely not being set because the guard statement is not being satisfied meaning